# How can I combine different dataframes into one csv in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, export-to-csv

I have 2 dataframes with different columns. And I want to combine those into 1 csv file. Both headers should be included and there shouldn't be empty value if columns aren't matched.

```
df1: Test1|Test2|Test3
       1  |  2  | 3

df2: Test4|Test5|Test6
       4  |  5  | 6
```

I tried to use `pd.concat`, but I need the result to be like below:

```
Test1|Test2|Test3
  1  |  2  | 3
Test4|Test5|Test6
  4  |  5  | 6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using Pandas [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) and setting the `mode` parameter to `"a"` for the second DataFrame to avoid overwriting the contents.

```py
df1.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
df2.to_csv("output.csv", index=False, mode="a")
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't know about mode="a" until I see your answer. Thanks a lot!